# Python Gurobi: How can I implement a maximum value of a decision variable in the objective function?

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

Hopefully someone can help me out. I am developing an optimization model where I minimize electricity costs over time (*t*) and over different transactions (*s*). (where: standard power(*p*)*costs of electricity (*c*) = electricity costs).

Now I am trying to implement a cost component in the objective function that is based on the maximum power consumption that occurred (some alike: *max(P[s,t])*). However, np.max() returns an error because P[s,t] is an unsupported class for np.max(). Also the Gurobi function gp.max_(P[s,t]) also gives an unsupported class error. Is there someone who has a solution?

Code:

```
obj = gp.quicksum(p[s, t] * Cost_elect[t]e for t in range(T) for s in range(S)) + gp.max_(p_batt_ch[s,t]*fixed_cost for t in range(T) for s in range(S))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the `max` constraint to a new auxiliary variable and the put this variable into the objective instead of the actual constraint.

```
maxobj = model.addVar()
max_constr = model.addConstr(maxobj == gp.max_(p_batt_ch[s,t] * fixed_cost
                             for t in range(T) for s in range(S)))

obj = gp.quicksum(p[s,t] * Cost_elect[t] for t in range(T) for s in range(S)) + maxobj)
```

[Gurobi documentation](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/py_model_agc_max.html)

Comment: Hi Thank you! This did work as i asked, but I failed to anticipate one very important part. I want to have the maximum of a column that summed every s at time t.

So basically the normal code: 
P_batt_charge['total']  = P_batt_ch.sum(axis= 1)
Pmax = P_batt_charge['total'].max()

So easy in a 'normal' script, but i cant get it to work within the optimisation. Do you also have a fix for this? :D